# simple rotation question in flash

Tags: flash

I'm a bit rusty of my trig, so I'm not sure the best way to do this ...

- I need to position 2 movie clips on the stage that relate to each other
- they can't be nested
- the registation points are in the center

assume "clip B" is 50 px to the left of "Clip A" as pictured in the diagram to  the left , when 
"clip A" is rotated, I need clip B to follow ( still 50px ) away but with new 
_x and _y relative to the rotation of "clip A" as in the diagram right

any help would be great

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlIII.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think your diagram is supposed to show A rotated in the second part right?

Basically you can consider the center of MovieClip B to be a point on a circle with the radius of 50 and with the angle based on A's angle. This code is for AS3 but I am guessing you are using AS2? All you need to do is add the underscore in front of x and y of the MovieClips. Also note this will rotate clockwise.

```
function rotateA(angleInDegrees:Number):void
{
    a.rotation = angleInDegrees;

    var bx:Number = Math.sin(angleInDegrees*(Math.PI/180))
    var by:Number = -Math.cos(angleInDegrees*(Math.PI/180))

    bx*=50;
    by*=50;

    bx+=a.x;
    by+=a.y;

    b.x = bx;
    b.y = by;
}
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! props to you ! yep, I guess the diagram didn't reflect that a was rotated - excatly what I was shooting for with a function that passes in the rotation argument. the trig is slowly coming back  - thanks again